# EF Core Migrations doesn't pick up all properties

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

When using EF Core Migrations the tooling isn't picking up all my properties, only the "Id" and some (not all) of the FK's (navigation properties). It also seems to understand the "Table Per Hierarchy" very well - as it has set up a discriminator where I wanted it to, but the migration file itself doesn't reflect the properties I have in my Model namespace (see github code).

My DbContext are located here: https://github.com/aredfox/TheConference/blob/master/InfoBooth/TheConference.InfoBooth.Data/InfoBoothContext.cs
My Model classes here: https://github.com/aredfox/TheConference/tree/master/InfoBooth/TheConference.InfoBooth.Core/Model

You can look at the generated "Initial Migration" at [ https://github.com/aredfox/TheConference/blob/master/InfoBooth/TheConference.InfoBooth.Data/Migrations/20170604125116_Initial.cs ]. There you'll see that it detected all the Id properties (defined in the base class `[Entity][1]`), but none of the other properties I of my [Model classes](https://github.com/aredfox/TheConference/tree/master/InfoBooth/TheConference.InfoBooth.Core/Model).

I used the approach of adding a Console App to run migrations (otherwise it won't work - see [Julie Lerman's tips](http://thedatafarm.com/data-access/no-executable-found-matching-command-dotnet-ef/) on getting started with EF Core). Thus when running migrations I do it this way: `dotnet ef --startup-project ../../TheConference.Infrastructure.ConsoleApp migrations add Initial`.

**Do I have to use *annotations* or *modelBuilder* or a form of *EntityTypeConfiguration* in EFCore to let EF know what I want to take?**.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

All of your class properties are like this

```
public string Title { get; }
```

i.e. read only auto properties.

EF Core does not support (map) such properties. In order to get them mapped, you need to provide property setters

```
public string Title { get; set; }
```

The access level does not really matter - `private`, `protected` or `internal` will work. The only requirement is to have a setter.

EF Core also allows mapping properties and using backing fields, but all that requires fluent API configuration and also most likely will not work with get only auto properties because they are backed with `readonly` fields.

Comment: To add bit more, the primitive properties & reference navigation properties needs setter. Collection navigations does not need setter. (It is common pattern for user to writer the collection initializer in constructor or default value).
Id was matched because the interface has setter defined & collection navigations were mapped.

Comment: Thanks mate. Just figure it out as well when cfg'ing them with the fluent API I got the error message that they were readonly and then my penny dropped... Thanks for the answer though! Stupid mistake, I just overlooked.

Comment: You are welcome, mate. It happens sometimes to all of us :)

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is right, but I must say also that I faced the same problem and changed the property that was not migrated as the following:

I had a `bool` property named `isFinishedCreation` but when I changed it to `IsFinishedCreation` efcore started seeing it and migrating it, I don't know if lower case or upper case has an effect on efcore but it happened with me.

so this is for anyone who might face this problem too.